# How i can create custom media query in tailwind css?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

For example, this media query:

```
@supports ((-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px)) or (backdrop-filter: blur(5px))) {
    @apply bg-black;
}
```

need write as (like as `@screen`):

```
@support blur5 {
   @apply bg-black;
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit tailwind.config.js file to add custom media queries. Here is some custom media query examples:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        '2xl': '1440px',
        '3xl': '1536px',
        'custom-height-mq': { 'raw': '((min-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 830px))' },
      }
    },
  },
```

Let me know, if you need more help.

Comment: Does the tailwindcss configuration support the scripting media query or will a plugin or custom css be needed?

Answer (score -2):

Wrapping your classes in `@responsive {}` directive will generate the class you wrote with the breakpoints defined in your config, eg. sm, md, lg and xl by default

```
@responsive {
  .my-class {}
}
```

With default breakpoints it will generate `sm:my-class` ``` md:my-class``lg:my-class ``` `xl:my-class`.

Comment: Why do I need a class? I need the equivalent of @screen